# Facebook RealTime Updates not reaching our Heroku Server in https:// and 301 redirected otherwise

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, heroku, https, real-time-updates

I'm trying to implement Facebook's RTU functionality to subscribe to page's conversations. So far I've gotten through all the steps - creating an app, subscribing to a page's conversations, connecting the page to my web-app. RTUs work on my local, but not on my Heroku app.

Here's a link to the facebook bugs page:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/822517191155290/

Here's how far I've got:
When I enable the Facebook App to send POST requests to:
https://..../fb_callback (https), we don't see anything in the logs.

On the other hand, when I enable the app to send POST requests to:
http://...com/fb_callback
I see that the request comes in and then there's a 301 redirect.

My guess is that the 301 redirect is to https... but I'm not sure of this.

What I can't figure out is why I can't see the POST requests to our log when they're sent to https.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does it work if you send a POST to the heroku url?

Comment: I am able to send a curl POST request to the heroku url and it shows up in the heroku logs as a POST request.

Comment: To add to the above.. we get POST requests from Twilio and Stripe just fine.